# Como bloquear todos os "radios" de um form ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu fiz um `quiz` com algumas perguntas e respostas, gostaria que alguém me ajudasse a resolver o seguinte problema, quero que ao clicar no botão de ver o resultado do `quiz`, todas as opções de resposta sejam travadas. O usuário não poderá mais alterar suas respostas.

Answer (score 3):

Basta definir/alterar o valor `disabled` do elemento para `true`.

```
document.getElementById("foo").disabled = true;
```

---

#### código de exemplo:

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('dog');

document.getElementById('block').onclick = function(){ 
    var len = radios.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        radios[i].checked = false; // caso tenha algum 'radio' marcado
        radios[i].disabled = true; 
    }
}
```

```html
<button id='block'>Bloquear Formulário</button>

<p><strong>1) Quantas patas tem um cachorro?</strong></p>
<form>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>1<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>2<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>3<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>5<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>Tenho certeza que não são 4<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode estar utilizando também desse modo abaixo

*Código do Renan.*

```
<button id='block'>Bloquear Formulário</button>

<p><strong>1) Quantas patas tem um cachorro?</strong></p>
<form>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>1<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>2<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>3<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>5<br>
  <input type='radio' name='dog'/>Tenho certeza que não são 4<br>
</form>
```

Apenas o código Javascript vai mudar, creio que seja melhor fazer desta forma

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('dog');

document.getElementById('block').onclick = function(){ 
    radios.forEach(function(el) {
       el.checked = false;
       el.disabled = true; 
    });
}
```

Comment: [Melhor (em performance) não é](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161763/4808), mas é uma alternativa.