# Como otimizar a soma dos elementos de um array?

Tags: javascript, array, desempenho

Preciso obter o valor da soma dos itens de um `array` em JavaScript.

A quantidade desses itens pode chegar facilmente a 2.000 itens.
Os itens são do tipo `int`, não é necessário testar.

```
ar = [1,3,5,...,2000];
```

Eu já tenho um `array` contendo os elementos, não preciso pegar o valor nos *inputs*. Quero somar os elementos desse `array`, de uma forma clara e objetiva.

Dessa forma estarei fazendo correto? Vou perder usando laço?

```
for (f=0;f<60;f++)
{
  valorSoma = ar[f]+valorSoma;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Somar Array Javascript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90841/somar-array-javascript)

Comment: Eu não consegui compreender a resposta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se quiser o jeito mais performático:

```js
var ar = [1, 3, 5, 8, 2000];
for (var i = 0, total = 0; i < ar.length; total += ar[i++]);
console.log(total);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Iterate.js).

Meu resultado comparando `for`, `for` com `length` externo (ao contrário da crença popular é mais lento que deixar interno), `reduce()` e `forEach()`:

[image: benchmark]

Então o seu jeito está correto, apesar de estar pegando apenas 60 itens e não estar escrito da melhor forma possível. Eu fiz o mais curto possível (já que a comparação parece ser com usar uma função pronta) sem perder performance.

Comment: Não consigo ter certeza de qual usar: for ou reduce(). Não tenho esse bagagem teórica toda, mas precisa muito escolher a melhor solução. Chego a ter 20 arrays com 2.000 itens, e preciso somá-los.

Comment: Se tem bastante e precisa da performance o `for` é mais interessante.

Comment: Será que no JSPerf  tem esse comparativo?

Comment: @durtto tem: https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-reduce-vs-for-loop. Não sei se ocorre o mesmo aí, mas no meu navegador, ao contrário da crença popular, deixar o `length` no *loop* fica mais rápido que extrair dele. Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152521/101

Comment: Sim, está com a razão. reduce() é mais lento ainda que filter().

Comment: http://jsbench.github.io/#a9a0d85633a1a589e7e2ae4e01dfe13e

Comment: @durtto essa comparação usa as 3 piores formas de fazer :)

Comment: sim, mas mesmo assim for fica na frente. Interessante como nem sempre funções nativas do javascript são mais rápidas que implementações manuais.

Comment: O último loop (no qual a propriedade length do objeto é reservada em uma variável) pode ser mais rápido em navegadores antigos, creio que atualmente os navegadores modernos reservam o tamanho de uma array na memória, e quando são modificadas só precisam atualizar esse tamanho novamente

Comment: @Someone sem dúvida.

Answer (score 10):

A partir do ES6, você pode usar [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) assim com [funções de seta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var numeros = [1, 3, 4, 2000];
var soma = numeros.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(soma);
```

Uma outra alternativa com [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while):

```js
var numeros = [1, 3, 4, 2000];
var tamanho = numeros.length;
var total = 0;

while(tamanho--) {
  total += numeros[tamanho];
}

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use reduce

```
var meuArray = [1, 2, 3, 200];

var countArray = meuArray.reduce(function(total, item) {
    return total+item;
}, 0);

alert(countArray);
```

Veja como o reduce funciona no [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp), e um ótimo video para aprender isso também [funfunfunction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl98eZpkp-c)

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta mudando o sentido, deseja adequar sua resposta?

Comment: +1 pelo link funfunfunction

Comment: Não, ja foi bem respondido acima.