# Como verificar se pelo menos um item do array tem valor igual ou maior que 2

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
array[0,2,0,0];
```

Preciso criar uma função que me retorne true se pelo menos um item do array tem valor igual ou maior que 2

Comment: O que vc ja tentou?

Comment: Pergunta interessante, vou juntar-me à festa e dar uma resposta também :) Esse valor "2" é fixo ou dinamico?

Comment: coloquei fixo, mas na vida real esse array chega a ter 2.000 posições.

Comment: Mas quero saber se pelo menos um dos índices é igual ou maior que 2

Comment: índices ou valores?

Comment: preciso saber se pelo menos um item tem valor igual ou maior que 2

Comment: Solução Drive-thru: `[0, 2, 0, 0].filter((i) => { return i >= 2 }).length > 0`

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Comment: Ajudou sim obrigado por me lembrar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tente user a função do array `some`

#### Verificar se existe algum elemento cujo valor é igual a 2

```js
var x = [0, 0, 2, 0];

function isTwo(value) {
  return value === 2;
}

var y = x.some(isTwo);

console.log(y);
```

#### Verificar se existe algum elemento maior ou igual a 2

```js
var x = [0, 0, 1, 0];

function maiorQueUm(value) {
  return value >= 2;
}

var y = x.some(maiorQueUm);

console.log(y);
```

Com as *arrow functions* do ES6 ficaria ainda mais simples:

```js
var x = [0, 0, 1, 0];
var y = x.some(it => it >= 2);

var w = [0, 0, 2, 0];
var z = w.some(it => it >= 2);

console.log(y, z);
```

Comment: Sua resposta faz sentido, porém faria sugestão de alterar no sentido de que a pergunta diz, MAIOR OU IGUAL. =)

Comment: Acho que é a resposta mais limpa

Comment: É, também, a mais performática, já que a execução parará no primeiro verdadeiro.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode fazer um filter e verificar o tamanho do array resultante como abaixo:

```js
var teste = [0,2,0,0];

function verificar(array) {
  return array.filter(function(item) {
    return item >= 2;
  }).length > 0;
}

console.log(verificar(teste));
```

Comment: Seu fiddle está dando erro. queria ve-lo funcionando. Fastly error: unknown domain: stacksnippets.net. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.

Details: cache-gru17123-GRU

Answer (score 7):

Aqui ficam várias maneiras diferentes:

```js
var arraryValida = [0, 2, 0, 0];
var arraryInvalida = [0, 1, 0, 0];
var valor = 2;

function testeFor(arr, match) {
    for (var x = 0, l = arr.length; x < l; x++) {
        if (arr[x] >= match) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function testeMax(arr, match) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math.max, arr) >= match;
}

function testeSome(arr, match) {
    return arr.some(nr => nr >= match);
}

[testeFor, testeMax, testeSome].forEach(function(fn, i) {
    console.log(fn.call(null, arraryValida, valor));
    console.log(fn.call(null, arraryInvalida, valor));
 console.log(i, '----');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLcctzq1/1

Comment: reduce() é claramente mais lento suas sugestões?

Comment: @durtto neste caso não sugeri o `reduce` pois não me parece semântico com a funcionalidade de procurar uma resposta tipo `true` ou `false`.

Comment: @durtto alguma das respostas serviu?

Comment: Ainda estou avaliando um critério para escolher a correta. 
Estou testando alguns conceitos contidos em todas as respostas.

Answer (score 6):

Segundo sua pergunta, basta saber se existe algum numero maior ou igual a dois, neste caso, um simples laço é suficiente...

```
function checkArray(myArray) {
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 
        if(myArray[i] >= 2){
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var myArray = array[0,2,0,0];
alert(checkArray(myArray));
```

Answer (score 5):

Aqui está uma maneira simples, para saber de **índices**:

```
function checkIndexTwoOrLarger(arr) {
    var achou = false;
    arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
        if (i >= 2)
           achou = true;
    });
    return achou;
}
checkIndexTwoOrLarger([0,0,0,2]);
```

Para **valores**, seria algo assim:

```
function checkValueTwoOrLarger(arr) {
    var achou = false;
    arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
        if (v >= 2)
           achou = true;
    });
    return achou;
}
checkValueTwoOrLarger([0,0,0,2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) é a melhor opção:

```js
function funcaoMaiorIgualQueDois(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 2;
}

var  res = [0,2,0,0].some(funcaoMaiorIgualQueDois);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: tem coisa errada ai

Answer (score 3):

Na série de perguntas que o AP está fazendo ([[1]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162708/101), [[2]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161754/101)), bem parecidas, eu vou insistir na simplicidade, no desempenho e até na legibilidade, ainda que esta última seja uma forma subjetiva de avaliar. Eu faria com um `for` simples e sem querer achar que está otimizando quando usa um cache do tamanho do *array* ([já mostrei que isso não funciona nos mecanismos modernos de JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161763/101)):

```js
function temValor(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i] >= 2) return true;
    return false;
}
var array = [0, 5, 1, 2];
console.log(temValor(array));
```

Se quiser generalizar o limite:

```js
function temValor(array, limite) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i] >= limite) return true;
    return false;
}
var array = [0, 5, 1, 2];
console.log(temValor(array, 2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Contains2.js).