# Como retornar a soma de números de um array com índices de valor maior ou igual a 2

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
array[0,2,0,0];
```

Preciso criar uma função que some somente os índices com valor maior ou igual a dois, como devo proceder?

> Nesse exemplo deve me retornar 2;
>       array[0,2,0,0];
>
> Nesse exemplo deve me retornar 7;
>         array[0,5,1,2];

Comment: Pergunta duplicada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162676/como-verificar-se-pelo-menos-um-%C3%ADndice-do-array-é-igual-ou-maior-que-2

Comment: Claro que não, fiz duas perguntas justamente porque são diferentes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu ainda prefiro o bom e velho laço manual (bem mais rápido, legível e simples):

```js
function Somar(array) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= 2) {
            total += array[i];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
var array = [0, 5, 1, 2];
console.log(Somar(array));
```

Note que não está somando índices e sim os valores dos elementos. Índice é outra coisa.

Se quiser generalizar o limite:

```js
function Somar(array, limite) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= limite) {
            total += array[i];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
var array = [0, 5, 1, 2];
console.log(Somar(array, 2));
```

Pode comparar e verá que a diferença de velocidade é grande. Já [demonstrei em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161763/101).

Para quem acha que número de linhas menor é melhor dá para fazer, só que fica menos legível:

```js
function Somar(array, limite) {
    for (var i = 0, total = 0; i < array.length; (total += array[i] >= limite ? array[i] : 0), i++);
    return total;
}
console.log(Somar([0, 5, 1, 2], 2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Sum.js).

Comment: Pode ter melhor desempenho devido aos overhead na chamada da função, porém eu não acho mais legível. Reduce, filter, map deixa o código mais otimizado e, para quem entende, mais simples.

Comment: Não deixa mais otimizado, como acabou de conformar, legibilidade é um pouco subjetivo, eu acho o meu bem mais legível, qualquer programador minimamente instruído entende bem ele, as outras formas não é qualquer que entende. Tem que ficar procurando em outras partes ou entender uma sintaxe no mínimo esquisita. Não tem nada de simples ter que usar duas funções onde cabe uma bem simples, pior ainda se tiver que escrever duas e chamar outras duas e para abstrair isso teria que ter uma quinta. Nada simples. Mas como eu falei, quem gosta... gosta.

Comment: Pode ser questão de opinião, mas sim, deixa mais simples. Um bloco de código com loops aninhados e condicionais na minha opinião não é mais legível. ECMA2015 implementou essas funções e pelo que acompanho da comunidade mundial em javascript, está sendo adotada pela maioria. Redução de linhas quer dizer sim otimização. Qualquer teste que se faça para trabalhos ou em plataformas de programação (HackerRank, facebook developers event, etc) é pesado o uso de ECMA2015 e muitas vezes a primeira pergunta do avaliador é: "Por quê foi usado laços aninhados se existe reduce em ECMA2015?"

Comment: **_porém eu não acho mais legível_** é muito subjetivo @LucasCosta

Comment: PS: espero que não confundam, então que fique bem claro: acho importante ter as duas formas nas respostas, e acho que ambas tem seus espaços. O que não dá é pra encarar gosto pessoal dando a entender coisa errada, como se reduce fosse melhor. É só um sugar, uma comodidade, que em certas situações pode ser prático. Nadinha mais.

Comment: @bigown, eu não entendo C# quanto à referência. De início já concordei com você que dessa forma tem melhor performance, achei que você entenderia que com otimizado quis enfatizar otimiza em linhas de código. Obrigado por compartilhar do seu conhecimento.

Comment: @LucasCosta Diminuir número de linhas não traz vantagem por si só. A minha tem duas linhas a mais. Fiz uma versão com apenas 5 linhas, bem menos que a sua, que não tem nada de errado. Não ficou mais legível que as minhas anteriores. Se ficou mais legível que a sua é bem discutível. Amontoar tudo não é legível, mas separar em várias coisas, ficar exigindo passos extras para consumir não dá para chamar de o mais legível que dá também. Particularmente eu acho menos legível, mas aceito quem diga que é mais legível. Coisas subjetivas são assim. Por isso que eu me apego mais às objetivas. Ganho mais

Comment: Esses comentários sobre otimização de código me arremete a matéria de complexidade de algoritmos, lembrando que a complexidade de um algoritmo recursivo (caso do reduce que chama a mesma função enquanto houver um elemento dentro do array, ou seja um loop executando uma função n vezes) é no melhor caso O(n).
Ja em um algoritmo utilizando apenas um loop, o melhor caso, e o pior caso é o mesmo O(n). Ver como referencia, a partir do slide 20: [link](https://www.ime.usp.br/~song/mac5710/slides/01complex.pdf)

Comment: Claro que no exemplo da pergunta, a performance não afetaria em muito,  já que a função dentro do reduce só e chamada uma vez, porem enfatizo que na otimização de um algoritmo nem sempre deve ser levada em consideração a quantidade de linhas ou a legibilidade, mas sim sua performance

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio não analisei essa questão, pode ser também, mas existe a desvantagem de *overhead* da função sendo chamada em todas iterações e eliminação de otimizações que ocorrem no *loop* também. Mesmo no melhor caso o `reduce()` será **bem** pior.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ah sim, obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Podes usar o `.reduce` (ES5) ou um ciclo `for` (à moda antiga).

Exemplos de ambos:

```js
var arr = [0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 5]; // a soma deve ser 10
var valor = 2;

function sumFor(arr, nr) {
    var soma = 0;
    for (var x = 0, l = arr.length; x < l; x++) {
        if (arr[x] >= nr) soma += arr[x];
    }
    return soma;
}

function sumReduce(arr, nr) {
    return arr.reduce(
        (sum, val) => sum + (val >= nr ? val : 0)
    );
}

console.log(sumFor(arr, valor));
console.log(sumReduce(arr, valor));
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btg0ag08/1/

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro você pode obter um array dos valores que são maior ou igual a 2 usando [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) e depois usar o [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para eferuar a soma:

```
function somarMaiorIgualQueDois(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 2;
}

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var res = [0,5,1,2].filter(somarMaiorIgualQueDois);
var soma = res.reduce(add, 0);

console.log(soma); // 7
```

```js
function somarMaiorIgualQueDois(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 2;
}

function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var res = [0, 2, 0, 0].filter(somarMaiorIgualQueDois);
var soma = res.reduce(add, 0);

console.log(soma); // 7
```

Answer (score 5):

Isto é apenas uma sugestão alternativa e contem um exemplo de teste de performance que você pode usar em todos scripts (se bem que performance neste tipo de coisa vai ser totalmente imperceptível)

Você poderia tentar fazer algo como usar um while mais limpo, se for para "tornar mais legível" escrita de código:

```js
/*
arr = seu array
min = valor minimo que o indice deve ter
*/

function SomaArray(arr, min)
{
    var sum = 0,
        i = arr.length; 

    while (i--) {
        current = arr[i];
        if (current >= min) sum += current;
    }

    return sum;
}

var meuArray = [0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 0];
var initiate = new Date().getTime();

console.log(SomaArray(meuArray, 2));

console.log("Terminou em:", new Date().getTime() - initiate, "ms");
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um filter e usar a função reduce para somar os componentes resultantes:

```js
var teste = [0,2,0,0];

function adicionar(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function somar(array) {
  return array.filter(function(item) {
    return item >= 2;
  }).reduce(adicionar, 0);
}

console.log(somar(teste));
```

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```