# Foreach em Javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

Olá, eu tenho um objeto em `JavaScript` e gostaria de verificar se todos os valores das chaves do objeto são diferente de `null`, `undefined`, 0, "" e " ".

Eu percorro cada value do meu objeto com o `forEach`, porém quero que a primeira condição seja executada apenas se todos os valores são diferente do que eu comentei acima.

No meu código, se apenas um valor já deixa de ser `null`, `undefined`, 0, "" ou " ", meu código executa a condição e não entra no else mais.

Beautified `JavaScript`:

```
let dados = {
    nome: nome,
    email: email,
    telefone: telefone,
    cursos: cursos,
    cidade: cidade
};
let condicao = false;
Object.values(dados).forEach(function (campo) {
    console.log(campo);
    if (campo !== "" && campo !== null && campo !== " " && campo !== false && campo !== 0 && campo !== undefined) {
        //Execute algo
    } else {
        if (condicao == false) {
            alert("Preencha todos os campos");
            condicao = true;
        }
    }
})
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como verificar se pelo menos um item do array tem valor igual ou maior que 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162676/como-verificar-se-pelo-menos-um-item-do-array-tem-valor-igual-ou-maior-que-2)

Comment: O método every() testa se todos os elementos do array passam pelo teste implementado pela função fornecida.  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fora de um método, eu imagino a resolução de uma forma simples e verbosa como a seguir:

```
let dados = { nome: '', email: 'email', telefone: 'telefone', cursos: 'cursos', cidade: 'cidade' };

let count = 0;

Object.values(dados).forEach(function (campo) {
    if (!campo || campo === ' ') {
        count++;
    }
});

if (count === 0) {
    console.log('todos preenchidos');
} else {
    console.log('falta preencher');
}
```

Só se atente a alguns detalhes:

- Em javascript, 0, nulo, undefined e em branco são valores que retornam false, então numa verificação se você utilizar "!var", para qualquer desses valores que estiver na variável, irá retornar false;
- Você utilizou "&&" para verificação, nesse caso o valor de uma variável teria que ser, segundo seu exemplo, nula, em branco, undefined, etc... e é impossível um valor ter todos esses atributos rsrs, nesse caso você deve usar "||", sendo assim, se o valor tiver qualquer dessas condições, ele retornará false

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte.

Comment: Ao invés do `forEach`, pesquise sobre o `every` ou `some` que a solução ficará mais simples.

Comment: sim, sim, mas pelo nível do código, parece que ele é novato na linguagem, então achei melhor colocar algo mais verboso como exemplo.

Comment: outro detalhe também é nunca usar verificação por "espaço" pois dependendo do caractere ele pode ser "invisível" porém não é "espaço", nesse caso você pode usar algo como "campo.length > 0"

Answer (score 2):

O objeto no JS é do tipo key-value.

Você pode usar o for...in, segue a documentação abaixo

```
//Objeto
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

//Para prop (propriedade) in obj (objeto) faça
for (var prop in obj) {
  // ctrl+shift+k (para abrir o console no mozilla firefox)
  console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}

//A saída (output) deverá ser:
// "obj.a = 1"
// "obj.b = 2"
// "obj.c = 3"
```

Referência:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: acho que apesar dotítulo da pergunta, essa resposta não esclarece o AP. Veja o texto da pergunta, e veja se consegue endereçar a dúvida real dele.

Comment: O for...in não é um foreach. Ele percorre as propriedades do objeto. A minha resposta foi mais um norte. No caso, ele poderia criar uma função, usar o for...in e simplesmente ver se a prop era vazia, nula, zero ou indefinida, e caso fosse, retornasse true.